#  ASP.NET MVC 3 Single-Page Application using Javascript/jQuery AJAX:  Memory  and Detached DOM Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

I have recently built an single-page ASP.NET MVC 3 with a JS/jQuery UI (on top of the view's HTML), the general idea of the Javascript work is below. I am encountering issues with GC not properly freeing memory and leaving a large number of elements (24,000 for the biggest form, 15-20k, and 1k depending on which form is loaded/unloaded) in Detached DOM (viewable in Chrome's Developer tools Heap Profiler).

```
 var MainApp = function () {
    var meBase = this;
    this.activeObject = undefined;

    this.someFunc = function (val1, val2, etc) {
        //Some operation here
    }
    this.GetView(x, y, z)
    {
        if (meBase.activeObject != null) {
            meBase.BustActive(x, y, z);
        } else {
            if (condition) {
                //Load static html via $.get
            } else {
                switch (activeObjectSelector) {
                    case CASEHERE:
                        self.activeObject = new SomeObject();
                        self.activeObject.BeginInit();
                        break;
                    case .....
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.BustActive = function (x, y, z) {
        if (meBase.activeObject.Destroy()) {
            meBase.activeObject = null;
            meBase.GetView(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
var SomeObject = function () {
    var meBase = this;
    this.Bindings = [];
    this.Container = "#somecontainer";
    //Some Properties

    this.Unbind = function () {
        $("#Somecontainer .bound").each(function () {
            if ($(this)["click"] && $.isFunction($(this)["click"])) {
                $(this).unbind('click');
            }
            if ($(this)["blur"] && $.isFunction($(this)["blur"])) {
                $(this).unbind('blur');
            } if ($(this)["change"] && $.isFunction($(this)["change"])) {
                $(this).unbind('change');
            }
            if ($(this)["mouseenter"] && $.isFunction($(this)["mouseenter"])) {
                $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
            } if ($(this)["mouseleave"] && $.isFunction($(this)["mouseleave"])) {
                $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
            }
        });

        //iterate through meBase.Bindings to remove any 'special' bindings such as 'live/die'
    }
    this.MapEvents = function () {
        //For Example

        $("#Somecontainer #element").click(meBase.SomeAction).addClass('bound');

        // create object with removal function for 'special' bindings such as 'live/die'
        // and push it into meBase.Bindings;
    }
    this.InitUI = function () {
        //Setup tabs, datepickers, etc
    }
    this.Destroy = function () {
        meBase.Unbind();

        //remove object fields and methods
        delete meBase.someProp;

        $(meBase.Container).empty();
        delete meBase.BeginInit;
        delete meBase.InitUI;
        delete meBase.MapEvents;
        delete meBase.SomeAction;
        delete meBase;
        return true;
    }
    this.SomeAction = function () {
        //Do something productive..hopefully
    }
    this.ProcessView = function (data) {
        $("#MainContainer").fadeOut(150, "swing", function () {
            $(this).empty().append(data);
        });
    }
    this.LoadView = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/somewhere/something',
            type: 'GET',
            success: meBase.ProccessView, error: SomeGlobalObject.LogAjaxError
        });
    }
    this.BeginInit = function () {
        //Load pages via ajax
        meBase.LoadView();
        meBase.InitUI();
        meBase.MapEvents();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have tried doing iterations with javascript to remove events and elements in .Destroy() function, and it substantially reduced the number of elements left in Detached DOM versus $(container).empty() or $(container).remove().  But my memory is never properly collecting back down, it just continually rises during each load/unload.  There are drops at random intervals, but not the amount I would expect.  Is it normal for so many elements to remain hung-up, or is there some fundamental issue with the way my code is functioning?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

First post, please be gentle...

Comment: After looking into this matter further, and speaking with various developers at conferences, I have come to the conclusion that it is just the way things are for now.  Others are experiencing the same issues with memory management.  You can easily fix this by having each "section" do postbacks and then each page work as a SPA.

Answer (score 1):

I've also recently been building some single-page apps in .Net MVC3.  I suspect your problems are arising because Microsoft, in their attempts to keep developers out of JS and in C#, mucks around with the Javascript and Jquery on your page pretty badly.

The best advice I can give you is that you need to ditch all of Microsoft's cruft, and build the html/js part of your app as though it were totally platform independent.  This means that you'll mostly be using the M in the MVC, and you'll only need enough Cs to manage your Ms.  If the View is all HTML and Javascript, life gets a lot simpler indeed.  Here's how to get started:

- Delete all pre-packaged server-side code, including the Razor or ASPX pages.
- Switch to static HTML files, static JS files
- (Optional) Use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to manage your JS dependencies (read the docs carefully, it seems weird at first, but it's incredibly powerful)
- (Optional) Use [Spine.js](http://spinejs.com/) to give your JS code some structure
- (Optional) Use [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for your client-side templating engine

Require and Spine have quickly become my favorite tools for building single-page apps.  They give you some very powerful and flexible tools to help you manage the increased volume of Javascript code you'll be writing in any single-page app.

Once you've got your client-side code *completely disconnected* from Microsoft's attempts to ruin Javascript, then you can focus on your data, which should use JSON-based Rest Services in MVC3.  You can get help with this [here](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/01/implementation-of-rest-service-with.html) and [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c18775).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you kindly for the insight(s).  I had a suspiscion it might have had something to do with MS, but was hoping it wasn't.  Thanks for the information and the time you spent gathering it all, I will be sure to look into those libs you mentioned.  Take care!

Comment: if you are going to bash a tool set, don't speculate but rather provide proof.  Everything posted is client side and doesn't depend on MS technology, just because MVC is being used on the server side. In your destroy method, try using remove as it will remove all bindings, children, and data elements associated with the element being removed.  Good Luck.

Comment: I wasn't exactly bashing the tool set, I was trying to explain that a lot of the Javascript added by Microsoft is there to support their server-side templating, sessions, post-backs, etc. If you're trying to build a single-page app that operates mostly client-side, their extra JS libraries are mostly overhead, and in my anecdotal experience, can cause some unexpected results.  So my only  'evidence' is that when I stopped using their JS stuff, my life got a little easier, and I felt more in control of what I was working on. :)